# How to ignore "Seems to be a pre-built javascript file...Try to require the original source to get better results." for Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack is throwing a warning: "This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results."

However, this library I am including is intentionally pre-built such that consuming applications do not need to replicate its build steps and configuration.

How do I ignore this warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix this by adding the path to the prebuilt module into your webpack config under module:

```
module: {
    // ...
    noParse: [
      '/node_modules/prebuiltlib/dist/build.js',
    ]
    // ...
}
```

This has the added benefit of slightly faster build times.

Answer (score -1):

I just copy and paste the same node_module  from another solution into my repo, it's works for me i got error for jspdf.js library of node module.
this is due to the different versions and code i guess.

Comment: Changes to the node_modules are not reflected to other people that also try to run your library, you really want to list the correct version in package.json.